# Russian characters in type column in windows file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

What the Russian characters in type column in windows file explorer?
Are these signs of a virus or malware?

[image]

Comment: Those characters look like [Cyrillic, which doesn't necessarily mean Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabets) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Russian verion of Visual Studio installed (and thats why Visual studio related file types registered in windows explorer with russian descriptions). 
Could you please check content of this column with list of files of other types (e.g. pictures/Office files or just /Windows/system32) opened?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I downloaded a complete iso containing the whole Visual Studio installation files and that included the Russian language pack.

In order to remove the Russian language pack, open the Visual Studio Installer. The Visual Studio Installer is available as a separate application alongside Visual Studio on your computer.
Inside the VS Installer, in front of your current edition, click on the More menu and select the Modify option; on the next page go to the Language Packs tab and uncheck the Russian language and continue with modifying the installation.